# Create a matrix with a given sparsity pattern and whose condition number is low

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matlab, symmetric-matrices, condition-number

In Matlab, I need to create a symmetric matrix with a given sparsity pattern and whose condition number is low ($\leq 10$). The matrix is sparse (more than half of its entries are zero).

From what I already know, generally if diagonal entries are larger and if the value of the entries are taken from a function, the condition number will be low.

---

#### Update

As an example of structure, we can consider Jacobian matrices or matrices whose graph is a star.

Comment: The identity matrix fullfills your conditions. You need to be more precise.

Comment: @nicomezi it has not the specified structure.

Comment: Well, more then half of the entries are zero, diagonal entries are larger then nondiagonal and those are taken by the null function. That is why I am asking you to be more precise.

Comment: @nicomezi I updated the question

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo the value of non-zero entries are random (random for top triangle, the same will be used for bottom triangle)

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Well I think when the values are set in that way, we can't say if it is positive definite or  Positive semidefinite. is that right?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo let me put it this way, can you build a matrix whose graph is a star with low condition number?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo it means off diagonal entries must represent the graph. vertex $v_i$ is connected to vertex $v_j$ if entry $(i,j) \neq 0$ otherwise it will be zero. So for a graph there are infinitely matrices that represent it. Inverse Eigenvalue Problem is building a matrix that represents a graph such that its eigenvalues equals to a list of values that is provided as input.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you are not using `sprandsym(n,density,rc)` with `density`$\geq 0.5$ and `rc`$\in (0.1,\infty)$ ([documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprandsym.html))?

Comment: I don't know what that is!!!